# "Only assignment, call increment..." Error On Closing Connection

Tags: c#, error-handling, sqlconnection

I'm a little rusty at C#, and can't figure out why I'm getting a message on `AWConn.Close;`:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection AWConn = new SqlConnection("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=MyServer/MyInstance; Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=true;");

        try
        {
            AWConn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        // Database stuff here...

        AWConn.Close;


    }
```

I'm sure this looks like a dumb question, but like I said it's been awhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SqlConnection.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx) is a method. You need to call it like;

```
AWConn.Close();
```

But instead of that, just use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects automatically.

```
using(SqlConnection AWConn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    try
    {
        AWConn.Open();
    }
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Instead of catching an `Exception`, catch instead `SqlException` which only exception type that `.Open()` method can throw.

Comment: Tried, but the system made me wait a little while :-)